# Is there a source for the claim that a dishonest person cannot do teshuvah?

Tags: sources-mekorot, repentance-teshuvah, sheker-false

If I recall correctly, I remember someone saying in a shiur a long time ago that a dishonest person cannot do teshuvah. Is there any source for this claim?

Comment: I've no source, but it stands somewhat to reason. I mean, someone thoroughly dishonest can't admit to himself that he did wrong, a key component of _t'shuva_.

Comment: What does this mean? Teshuvah means that he no longer acts dishonestly and pays back what he has stolen.

Comment: @msh210 That is exactly the type of dishonesty that I was referring to, lying to himself and to others. Shall I edit the question to replace the words "dishonest person" with "habitual liar"?

Answer (score 5):

Anyone can do Teshuva but a dishonest person can’t always pay back and make amends.

The Gemora (Bova Basra 88B) says קשה עונשן של מדות יותר מעונשן של עריות

*The punishment for using false measures is more severe than the punishment for transgressing the prohibition of forbidden sexual relations.*

The Gemora goes on to discuss why and says מאי עודפייהו דהתם אפשר בתשובה והכא **לא אפשר בתשובה**

*in the case of one who engages in forbidden relations, he has the possibility of repentance. But in the case of one who uses false measures, **there is no possibility of repentance** because he has no way of knowing whom he cheated, and is therefore unable to return the stolen money.*

However the Gemora (Bava Kama 94B-95A)discusses Teshuva for  theft. Even if the thief doesn't know who he stole from he can try to pay back by paying communal needs. (Tosfos says that doing so isn't a real repayment)

It is said over in the name of the Chofetz Chaim that Gezel Shinah (keeping someone else up) has no way to be paid back